# Conditional expected value- gaussian variables

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution, conditional-expectation

I have a task:

> $X$ is random variable with normal distribution $N(0,1)$, $Y$ has $N(0,2)$ distribution. $X,Y$ are independent. Calculate:
>   $$E(X^3\mid X+Y)$$

I know how to do it from definition. But I want to complicate $X^3$ and use of measurable and independence of $X+Y$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $X \sim N\left(0,\sigma^2_X\right)$ and $Y \sim N\left(0,\sigma^2_Y\right)$ are independent then, given that $X+Y=c$, I think you have the conditional distribution $X \sim  N \left(c \frac{\sigma_X^2}{\sigma_X^2 + \sigma_Y^2}, \frac{\sigma_X^2 \sigma_Y^2}{\sigma_X^2 + \sigma_Y^2}\right)$ from which you can find $E[X^3 \mid X+Y=c]$ and thus $E[X^3 \mid X+Y]$

Comment: I don't want to find distribution. For example if i wanted to calculate $E(X|X+Y)$. $E(X|X+Y)=E(X-\frac{1}{3}(X+Y)+\frac{1}{3}(X+Y))|X+Y)$. $Cov(X-\frac{1}{3}(X+Y), X+Y)=0$, so $X-\frac{1}{3}(X+Y), X+Y$ are independent. We have $E(X|X+Y)=\frac{1}{3}(X+Y)$. It is possible to solve above problem with similar method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to proceed by using normal regression, as you suggest in the comment. Indeed, denoting $S = (X+Y)/3$, $Z = X-S$, and using the independence of $Z$ and $S$,
$$
\mathrm E[X^3\mid X+Y] = \mathrm E[(Z+S)^3\mid X+Y] =  \mathrm E[Z^3 + 3Z^2 S + 3Z S^2 + S^3\mid X+Y] \\
= \mathrm E[Z^3] + 3S\mathrm E[Z^2] + 3S^2 \mathrm E[Z] + S^3.
$$
Now noting that $Z$ has a centered Gaussian distribution,
$$
\mathrm E[X^3\mid X+Y] = 3S\mathrm{Var}(Z)+ S^3 = \frac{8(X+Y)}{9} + \frac{(X+Y)^3}{27}.
$$
(You have to check the computations!)

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what i wanted :)